# Best way to search for character and add a character after it in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Groovy question. I have a string like this:

```
 {john=1054.39, bob=345.67, fred=12.45}
```

Everytime I see an equal sign within the string I'd like to add a $ after it. What's the best method to do this in Groovy and keeping the amount of code to the barest minimum? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all `=\d+` with `=\$$1`

```
def str = '{john=1054.39, bob=345.67, fred=12.45}'

def modified = str.replaceAll('=(\\d+)', '=\\$$1')

assert modified == '{john=$1054.39, bob=$345.67, fred=$12.45}'
```